# Just the month january not working

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

In this query I found the weeks of month, for example november begin 1th Wednesday and ends sunday 5.
These are the first week on november.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 WITH days AS
  (SELECT to_date('01012017','ddmmyyyy') + level-1 date_in
 FROM  dual
  CONNECT BY level < 32)
 SELECT date_in,
  TO_CHAR(date_in,'IW') - TO_CHAR(TRUNC(date_in,'MM'),'IW') + 1 week_number
 FROM  days) where week_number = 1;
```

The week_number can change depending of the weeks of the month, but in January is not working.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "not working"? January 2017 began on a Sunday, and as the weeks returned by your query run Monday - Sunday your query appears to work just fine. Thanks.

Comment: i need to get when start and end the weeks of month (x) for example november has 5 weeks in my case the weeks began monday a finish sunday. the last query work fine in the other month except january. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear for me but perhaps you are looking for this:

```
SELECT TRUNC (next_day(TRUNC(TO_DATE('20022017','ddmmyyyy'), 'mm'),'monday') - 1), 'IW') AS first_week
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit unclear as to what you're looking for, but perhaps the following query will help you on your way:

```
WITH YEAR_START AS (SELECT TO_DATE('01012017', 'DDMMYYYY') AS FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR
                      FROM DUAL),
     MONTH_START AS (SELECT FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
                       FROM YEAR_START
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT ADD_MONTHS(FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR, LEVEL) AS FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH
                       FROM YEAR_START
                       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11),
     MONTH_START_AND_END AS (SELECT FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH,
                                    ADD_MONTHS(FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH, 1) - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH
                               FROM MONTH_START),
     ABS_MONTH_WEEKS AS (SELECT FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH,
                                LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH,
                                TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH, 'IW')) AS ABS_FIRST_WEEK_OF_MONTH,
                                TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH, 'IW')) AS ABS_LAST_WEEK_OF_MONTH
                           FROM MONTH_START_AND_END),
     REL_MONTH_WEEKS AS (SELECT a.*,
                                1 AS REL_FIRST_WEEK_OF_MONTH,
                                ABS_LAST_WEEK_OF_MONTH - CASE
                                                           WHEN ABS_FIRST_WEEK_OF_MONTH > ABS_LAST_WEEK_OF_MONTH THEN 0
                                                           ELSE ABS_FIRST_WEEK_OF_MONTH-1
                                                         END AS REL_LAST_WEEK_OF_MONTH
                           FROM ABS_MONTH_WEEKS a)
SELECT *
  FROM REL_MONTH_WEEKS;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: How are you defining "week"? If  you're looking for "how many weeks does a particular month have at least one day in", that's `REL_LAST_WEEK_OF_MONTH` (relative last week of month) from the `REL_MONTH_WEEKS` common table expression in the query above.